# How can I test chrome.storage.sync.get() value with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, storage, react-testing-library

My React component contains a handler like this one which is called in a onClick function of a button:

```
const handleSaveInformationButtonClick = () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ information }, () => {
      // do something
    })
  }
```

I would like to test the value of the key "information" in the storage using Jest and react-testing-library. I wrote this test :

```
test("save new information into browser storage", () => {
    const { rerender } = render(<MyComponent />);
    const inputInformation = screen.getByTestId("main-input");
    const buttonSave = screen.getByTestId("main-button");
    const newInformation = "something here";
    fireEvent.change(inputInformation, { target: { value: newInformation } });
    fireEvent.click(buttonSave);
    rerender(<MyComponent />);
    expect(chrome.storage.sync.get("information")).toBe(newInformation);
});
```

I added chrome as global variable inside package.json :

```
"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "chrome": {}
    },
    ...
```

but when I run the test, I got :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined
on line : 'expect(chrome.storage.sync.get("information")).toBe(newInformation);'
```

How can I test this please ?